# How to sort an array of objects(Points) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

So I wanna sort an array of Points using the built in sorting method, by a specific coordinate, say x. How can I do this? Heres a sample code:

```
Point A[] = new Point[10];
// ... Initialize etc.
Arrays.sort(A, x-coordinate);
```

Is there a built-in comparator for x-coordinates in Point Class? If not, how can I create one and use it. An example would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`Point` isn't `Comparable` so you'll need to write your own comparator and pass it in when calling `Arrays.sort`. Luckily, that's not too hard:

```
class PointCmp implements Comparator<Point> {
    int compare(Point a, Point b) {
        return (a.x < b.x) ? -1 : (a.x > b.x) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

Arrays.sort(A, new PointCmp());
```

Comment: Please use any two of <, ==, >. People use subtraction all the time for this. One of them will have a subtraction that overflows, and boom.

Comment: Why? If you're working with points on a GUI then it's fine. Or you've got a physical screen more than 2G pixels across (to allow for signedness issues). If that's true, I hate you!

Comment: It's a "cute programmer trick" to use subtraction instead of <, >, ==. Makes your code harder to read and introduces the possibility of bugs for no real benefit. If you were on my project and wrote this, I would tell you to try again... :)

Comment: OTOH, if you're going to work with `Point2D.Double` or `Point2D.Float` then you'll want to do it the way I've updated my answer to.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `Double.compare(a.x, b.x)`. Shorter, and near impossible to get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Apache Commons Bean Comparator

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

And then do something like

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator;

Arrays.sort(A, new BeanComparator("x"));
```

Comment: How many projects don't already have apache commons? I haven't worked on a big project that didn't have it as a dependency somewhere down the maven chain

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Chill out, it shows an interesting way of abstracting a comparator by a field, OP can write one of his own if they choose