# How to sort objects in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an arraylist of objects by a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535124/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-property)
>   [What is the sorting algorithm for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228659/what-is-the-sorting-algorithm-for-java)

I have a class in java that keeps record of `diffSeconds`.

```
class fileObj
    {
        public String fileName; 
        public Date modificationTime; 
        public long diffSeconds;     

        fileObj()
        {
            modificationTime = null; 
        }
    }
```

I have a forloop that makes multiple instances of the `fileObj` class and adds them to a list.

```
List<fileObj> fileView = new ArrayList<fileObj>();
for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
       {
         fileView.add(new fileObj());
       }
```

Assuming that each class has a `diffSeconds` values assigned to them, how can i order the list depending on the value (largest first)

Comment: @Mike L.: please read the homework tag wiki.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an arraylist of objects by a property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535124/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-property) and [How to sort an array of objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077746/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objectspoints-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort(fileView)`; and implement `Comparable` interface and write implemented method `compareTo(fileObj arg0)` which decide for sorting your list.

For implementation,

```
class fileObj implements Comparable<fileObj>

@Override
    public int compareTo(fileObj arg0) {

        if(this.diffSeconds > arg0.diffSeconds )
        return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
```

[Reference:](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

**Detail Coding.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class SortExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<fileObj> fileView = new ArrayList<fileObj>();
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
               {
                 fileView.add(new fileObj(j));
               }
        Collections.sort(fileView);

        for(fileObj obj: fileView){
            System.out.println("File " + obj.getDiffSeconds());
        }


    }

}
class fileObj implements Comparable<fileObj>
{
    public String fileName; 
    public Date modificationTime; 
    public long diffSeconds;     

    fileObj()
    {
        modificationTime = null; 
    }

    fileObj(long diffSeconds)
    {
        modificationTime = null;
        this.diffSeconds = diffSeconds;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(fileObj arg0) {

        if(this.diffSeconds > arg0.diffSeconds )
        return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    public long getDiffSeconds() {
        return diffSeconds;
    }

    public void setDiffSeconds(long diffSeconds) {
        this.diffSeconds = diffSeconds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [comparator](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html&ei=S35dUPStM8i00QXx3IDADQ&usg=AFQjCNGDXaJ95_rdRgYPLcMa6V9gczDyEg&sig2=DoL8WO-K_Hhc-1XQVcbFOQ) or [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link below :-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Search for the sort method which takes objects as parameter and implement comparable interface in your class.