# Sorting array of objects by field

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, field

I have objects

```
Person{
    String name;  
    int age;
    float gradeAverage;
    }
```

Is there an easy way to sort

```
Person[] ArrayOfPersons
```

by age?

Do I have to use Comparable or Comparator? I don't fully understand them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of objects(Points) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077746/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objectspoints-in-java)

Comment: I think Java 7 (Net Beans 7.4)

Comment: You have to come up with some way to compare two `Person`(s); the usual way would be to make `Person` implement `Comparable<Person>` or to write a `Comparator<Person>`. They would be used to compare people.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just for completeness, when using Java 8, you can use [`Comparator.comparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to create a simple comparator for some attribute, e.g. `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)`, or using lambda, like `Comparator.comparing(p -> p.age)`, if there is not getter method for the age.

This makes it particularly easy to *chain* comparators for different attributes, using [`thenComparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-), e.g. for sorting primarily by age, and then by name in case of ties:

```
Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).thenComparing(Person::getName)
```

Combine that with [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29), and you are done.

```
Arrays.sort(arrayOfPersons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
```

Comment: Keep it on , I am really happy with awesome people using functional programming features in java 8 :)

Comment: Using the Comparator is also more flexible (say, if you want to sort on different fields depending on UI input), since you can have more than one of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can check for age using a getter in your loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < persons.length - 1; i++) {
    Person p = persons[i];
    Person next =  persons[i+1];
    if(p.getAge() > next.getAge()) {
        // Swap
    }
}
```

However implementing Comparable is the convenient way

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    String name;  
    int age;
    float gradeAverage;

    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        if(this.getAge() > other.getAge())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getAge() == other.getAge())
            return 0 ;
        return -1 ;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age ;
    }
}
```

You can check [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) documentation also

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the Comparable interface to make your class comparable. Make sure to override the compareTo method then.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    String name;
    int age;
    float gradeAverage;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        if(this.age < p.getAge()) return -1;
        if(this.age == p.getAge()) return 0;
        //if(this.age > p.getAge()) return 1;
        else return 1;
    }

    //also add a getter here
}
```

Comment: I always confuse when to return `-1` and when `+1`, so I prefer `return Integer.compare(this.age, p.getAge())`. Shorter, and foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just implement the `Comparable` interface.

Here's an example :

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public int age;
    public String name;

    public int compareTo(Person other){
        return this.age == other.age ? 0 : this.age > other.age ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PersonCompare {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person("Test1",10);
    Person p2 = new Person("Test2",12);
    Person p3 = new Person("Test3",4);
    Person p4 = new Person("Test4",7);

    Person[] ArrayOfPersons = {p1,p2,p3,p4};
    Arrays.sort(ArrayOfPersons);

    for(Person p: ArrayOfPersons) {
        System.out.println(p.getName()+"--"+p.getAge());
    }
}
}


class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
String name;
int age;

Person(String name, int age){
    this.name=name; this.age=age;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Person other) {
    if(this.getAge() > other.getAge())
        return 1;
    else if (this.getAge() == other.getAge())
        return 0 ;
    return -1 ;
}
}
```